# JavaScript: What does it mean if an object's name is written all uppercase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

While learning how to write a good JavaScript plugin, I was taking a look at the JavaScript files from Twitter Bootstrap (which uses jQuery).

The [collapse plugin](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/collapse.js) has this code at the beginning:

```
var Collapse = function (element, options) {
    this.$element      = $(element)
    this.options       = $.extend({}, Collapse.DEFAULTS, options)
    this.transitioning = null

    if (this.options.parent) this.$parent = $(this.options.parent)
    if (this.options.toggle) this.toggle()
  }

  Collapse.DEFAULTS = {
    toggle: true
  }
```

`var Collapse = function` seems to be the constructor that sets up some variables, including the object `this.options`. This seems to be a merge of the default options and custom options that are passed to the function, so that custom options overwrite/add to the defaults.

This is what I understand – what I don't understand why the object's name containing the default options is written in uppercase letters: **`Collapse.DEFAULTS`**? Is this something like a constant?

Comment: It doesnt't really mean anything, someone just decided to write it in uppercase.

Comment: @adeneo:best answer...

Comment: Obviously, the author just wanted to mark it as a kind of constant.

Comment: ECMAScript 6 introduces constants. Some modern browsers support the `const` keyword but here it's not a constant. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All upper case identifiers have no special meaning in JavaScript. Some people use them to indicate that a value should be *treated* as if it were a constant, but nothing in the language actually prevents them from being overwritten.